# "Home" link to indicate one's home, rather than the home page

Tags: navigation, e-commerce

A client is developing an ecommerce website with category links in the primary navigation. The links are to be named "Garden", "Home", etc.

I'm concerned that the "Home" link will be mistaken for a link to the home page, given its prominent position in the top navigation of the site.

I've found nothing online to indicate how others resolve this potential confusion. Are there any established techniques for handling this?

Comment: 'Homeware' seems to be a fairly common alternative. See, for example, [homebase.co.uk](http://www.homebase.co.uk/) and [next.co.uk](http://www.next.co.uk/)

Comment: "House" is another alternative.

Comment: We ended up renaming it to "Home Collection".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple ideas,

1. Place the links under a Department heading. This will separate "Home" from other navigation, distancing it from being interpreted as a link to the home page.
2. Use another word along with Home, such as "Home Decor" used by menards.com and lowes.com.

Answer (score 1):

Don't think Home is forbidden word. In context (Garden, etc.) it will be understandable. Besides you could point it with title (which pops up on mouseover).

Then you could try a simple user test, asking user to choose a menu for purchasing some goods fron Home category.

At least, you could change the name to 'House', etc.

Comment: I'd suggest doing the user test the other way around and asking the user to navigate to the homepage. If a significant number of users click on the home category instead, you've got a problem.

Comment: @Racheet This task will complement the test, you are right.